# TwitterLoginButton does not respond

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I implemented the TwitterLoginButton as shown on the example on https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login to allow login into my app using twitter. I am using Android Studio and installed Fabric plugin to get started and registered my app with it. I implemented the code exactly as mentioned but when I click on Twitter button, nothing happens.

My activity Layout is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
    tools:context="com.rayat.pricewiz.view.activity.SplashScreen">
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!--<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" android:visibility="invisible">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Get STARTED"
                android:id="@+id/btnGetStarted"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/transparent_rounded_box"
                />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="242dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnGetStarted"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnGetStarted"
            android:id="@+id/loginForm"
            android:background="@drawable/login_form">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layoutEmail"
            android:weightSum="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.14"
                    android:src="@drawable/login_form_email_icon"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txtEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_weight="0.72"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.14"/>
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layoutEmail"
                android:id="@+id/layoutPassword"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imgPassIcon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.14"
                    android:src="@drawable/login_form_passwd_icon"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                    android:layout_weight="0.72"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.14"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layoutPassword"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/layoutLang"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imgLangIcon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.14"
                    android:src="@drawable/login_form_lang_icon"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.80"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:entries="@array/language"
                    android:prompt="@string/select_language"
                    android:id="@+id/selLanguage"
                    style="@style/SpinnerAsEditText"
                    android:background="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layoutLang"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_selector"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/login"
                    android:onClick="login"
                    android:text="@string/login">
                </Button>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/splashScreenMargin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/splashScreenMargin"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/socialLoginForm"
        android:background="@drawable/login_form">
        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnLoginFacebook"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/facebook_f"
            />
        <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTwitterLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnLoginFacebook"/>
        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/btnLogingplus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnTwitterLogin"
            android:text="Log in with Google+"
            />
        <Button android:text="Log in with email"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:background="@drawable/orange_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnLogingplus"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/envelope"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is how I implemented the login:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
//Twitter login
twitterButton = (TwitterLoginButton)
        findViewById(R.id.btnTwitterLogin);
twitterButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
        // Do something with result, which provides a
        // TwitterSession for making API calls
        Log.w("twitter logged","twitter logged");
        TwitterSession session =
                Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
        String token = authToken.token;
        String secret = authToken.secret;
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        // Do something on failure
    }
}); }
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens and no twitter authorization page appears. I have twitter app installed.

Please help.

Thanks,
Noorul

Answer (score 0):

Your Oncreate() you define **setContentView()** first then set **Fabric.With()**  but in twitter integration there is wrong set these flow:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Make Sure you got succeed:)
Still put my code here for your referance...!!!

**activity_twitter.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**TwitterIntegrationDemo.java :**

```
package com.twitter.dhruv.twitterexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthToken;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;


public class TwitterIntegrationDemo extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
    private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "Your Key";
    private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "Your Secret";

    private TwitterLoginButton twitterLoginButton = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        twitterLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;
                String userName = session.getUserName();

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the login button.
        twitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
 }
```

**build.gradle :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.twitter.dhruv.twitterexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.twitter.dhruv.twitterexample" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TwitterIntegrationDemo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="Auto-Generated Value" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**MUST REMEMBER :**

***TwitterLoginButton*** NOT SUPPORTED IN DIALOG VIEW :)